# Combine the columns in file 1 to the columns in file 2 - should be simple - but something strange is happening

Tags: text-processing

I need to combine the columns in file 1 to the columns in file 2, usually I would use paste and it would work. Both files are tab delimited (checked by opening the text file in libre office calc and selecting tab delimited and it opens with all the columns correctly separated, also show with tab delimited if i open it as a text file)

So my two files look like this (but with over 8000 lines):

File 1:
OTUTaxonomy
Otu000001Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Bacilli(100);Lactobacillales(100);Enterococcaceae(100);Enterococcus(100);
Otu000002Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Ruminococcaceae(100);Faecalibacterium(100);
Otu000003Bacteria(100);"Bacteroidetes"(100);"Bacteroidia"(100);"Bacteroidales"(100);"Prevotellaceae"(100);Prevotella(100);

File 2

1   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  2   20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  3   30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  4   40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  5   50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  6   60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  7   70  71  72  8   9   NEG POS
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   42  0   0   0   0   37  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   5   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   13  0   22  33299   23691   30181   18512   36843   33351   911 22188   1   15688   8349    79  0   1   0   0
6765    0   3805    456 3950    1093    4330    0   6614    6374    3376    7866    0   3462    0   0   0   0   3196    5209    3099    7108    0   0   4862    2732    0   4026    7528    0   4795    6919    8494    3605    6886    1762    0   0   6125    0   0   0   2222    0   5177    0   9233    0   0   0   8674    4413    14251   7955    2161    2569    1942    1840    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   9320    0   0   53  1768    6104    0   0
0   11  0   14  20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   25  0   18798   593 31  0   27  20  168 0   44  35  0   33  2273    0   0   0   13  7   23  17  0   0   15934   0   25258   67  1124    78  0   17078   92  10  23000   0   9   11  0   0   0   70  5454    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   31  0   0   0   11585   21  0   0

But when i paste these two files together it keeps the columns separated fine, but it staggers the lines, so that file 1 lines are on 1, 3, 5, 7 etc and file 2 lines are on 2, 4, 6, 8, etc

Does anyone have any idea whats going on, is it due to the size of the file? and how do i resolve it?

it should be noted that if i save the text files in libre office calc as tab separated .csv files the paste works correctly. but if i convert the text files via command line the paste function fails and does the staggered problem mentioned earlier.

It should also be noted that if the size of the file is reduced form 8000 to 100 then the paste function also works

Comment: The formatting of the files in the question seems wrong. Please fix it and/or share a copy of the files somewhere

Comment: yeah there seems to be something odd happening when i paste the data in to the question box, for a start it gets rid of the tab and replaces with space. how do I share a copy?

Comment: There are multiple websites that let you do this, one example is [tinyupload](http://tinyupload.com/).

Comment: This is vaguely suggestive of a line ending problem.